# PHP crypt password

Tags: php, authentication

A simple Registration and login page for a website. I am trying to crypt the password + salting. That's what I have done but I am not sure if its correct.

This is what happens in the registration page:

```
$blowfish = '$2a$10$';
$salt = '8dF$d_3';
$hashedPass = crypt($password,$blowfish . $salt);
```

In the database, the password "RAYray99" is stored as "$2a$10$8dF$d_3$$$$$$$$$$$$$$.wxsfa7X.nkcGqldJ9fujdd8eY.H85uC"

---

**On the login page, I am stuck on how to check the password entered with the password in the database.**

This is the loging php script that verifies the user:

```
mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_pass") or die(mysql_error());
//select the database or return error message
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("database does not exist");

$email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
$email = strip_tags($email);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$password = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_POST['password']); // filter everything but numbers and letters
$password = crypt($password);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password' AND activateemail='1'"); 
$login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($login_check > 0){  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
    // Get member ID into a session variable
    $id = $row["id"];   
    session_register('id'); 
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    // Get member username into a session variable
    $username = $row["username"];   
    session_register('username'); 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    // Update last_log_date field for this member now
    mysql_query("UPDATE members SET lastlogin=now() WHERE id='$id'"); 
    // Print success message here if all went well then exit the script
    header("location: account.php"); 
    exit();
} // close while

} else {
// Print login failure message to the user and link them back to your login page
  print '<br /><br /><font color="#FF0000">ERROR TRY AGAIN </font><br />;
  exit();
}
```

**My question is how would I verify the login passsword entered on the login page with the 1 in the database.**

Thank you,
Ray

Comment: Don't encrypt the password... hash it instead!  And get rid of your `<font>` tags.  Those have been deprecated for years!  Finally, your `Location:` header must be an absolute URL, according to the RFC.  Yes, a relative path will *generally* work, but you don't want to end up into trouble when it doesn't.  Also, you are subject to SQL injection.  **Stripping slashes is not an appropriate protection** against SQL injection!!  Learn PDO with prepared queries.

Comment: Why do you encrypt the password instead of hashing (decryption almost impossible) it?
The filtering of the password makes it more unsafe! By the way [`ereg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/function.ereg-replace.php) is deprecated.

Comment: A tip unrelated to your question, you don't need to put you variables in quotes to use them. For example, your connect call can just be `mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass)`

Comment: @Brad @ComFreek "[crypt()](http://php.net/crypt) — One-way string hashing" `crypt()` does hash. Maybe you're thinking of [Mcrypt](http://php.net/mcrypt)?

Comment: @Wiseguy, learn something new everyday, you're right!  What a stupidly named function...

Answer (score 1):

To verify the password you should be hashing the entered one exactly the same way you did when you stored it in the first place.

I see some issues with what you have. First, the blowfish string for `crypt()` specifies, according to the PHP docs, that after your `$2a$10$` should be a 22 character string from the alphabet of `./0-9A-Za-z`. Your salt isn't following that, so the hash function is probably failing completely (though I'm not certain).

Also, your salt shouldn't be a constant in your app, it should be unique to each user and stored in the db along with their hashed password.

Finally, you shouldn't be doing those transformations to the password before hashing it. Break out a function that has the plaintext password as input, and outputs the hashed password. Use this function both when you store the password, and when you attempt to validate the login. That way you know for sure it should match the database.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a mapper for my sql queries (doctrine2).

My passwords are saved with md5 + salt in my db

```
public function setPassword($password) {
    $this->_password = self::encodePassword ( $password );
    return $this;
}
/**
 * This function encodes the password to md5 after adding a salt
 * @param string $password
 */
public static function encodePassword($password) {
    $salt = 'dsa7893ujlksdsagkz27392kjsjaldksju928ikljda27';
    return md5 ( $password . $salt );
}
```

My login looks like this ...

```
/**
 * Executes an authentication try
 *
 * @throws Zend_Auth_Adapter_Exception if the authentication failed
 * @return Zend_Auth_Result
 */
public function authenticate()
{
        //check if login is correct
        try{
                $user = $this->_em->getRepository('App_Model_User')
                    ->findOneBy(
                        array(
                            '_email' => $this->_login,
                            '_password' => App_Model_User::encodePassword( $this->_password )
                        )
                );
        }catch( Exception $e ){
                throw new Zend_Auth_Adapter_Exception( 'authentication failed', 0, $e );            
        }
```

.............

Comment: I would recommend to replace `md5` by `sha256` or `sha512`.

Comment: what is the length of these algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
$str = "$2a$10$8dF$d_3$$$$$$$$$$$$$$.wxsfa7X.nkcGqldJ9fujdd8eY.H85uC";

if (preg_match('/^(.{7})(.{7})(.+?)$/', $str, $m))
{
     $blowfish = $m[1];
     $salt = $m[2];
     $hashedPass = $m[3];
     $validHashedPass = crypt($password,$blowfish.$salt);

     if ($validHashedPass == $hashedPass)
     {
          good pass
     }
     else
     {
          wrong auth
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a class built just for this case. It uses the `sha1()` hashing function and `PDO` prepared statements to prevent SQL injections. I'll try to find it and post it here, but if I don't, this is my advice to you:

- Use a hashing function, not a crypting one.
- Don't use `mysql_*` as it does not support prepared statements. Use PDO or at the very leat, `mysqli`.

Comment: Thank you, and if you find it please do post it. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

As @Brad pointed out it'll be simpler (and to some extent safer) to hash the passwords instead of encrypting them.

MySQL supports both MD5 and SHA1 hashes anyhow.

One of the advantages of going this route is you can do either:

```
$pass = md5($salt . $pass);
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user' AND pass = '$pass';";
```

OR directly on the database

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user' AND pass = MD5('{$salt}{$pass}')";
```

Comment: PHP`s `crypt()` function isn't two way encryption. The name is totally misleading (add another point against the PHP base library). The PHP docs even say "crypt — One-way string hashing" on the function's page.

Comment: You're totally right, I confused it with the mcrypt function and did not verify